# Post to news feed with Facebook SDK without login in

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk, feed

Is there a way to post on the user wall without having to do login?
Going thought the documentation i can do this but the user has to do [login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/feed-dialog-using-ios-sdk/), which i don´t want cause this is a simple app.

I know there is a tutorial in the facebook developers website, because i found it and only later i realize that. Something using "publish_stream" permissions, if someone can point me in the right direction i appreciate.

Comment: What is it exactly that you want? Anonymous facebook access?

Comment: No, no. I want to share "stuff" and now i have a button to login and a button to publish. I want to incorporate the two of them in one button. Like an "auto-login"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not automatic (which would violate Platform Policy anyway), but you can use the Feed Dialog for this:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: "example assumes that the user is already logged in and has authorized your application", so i would still had to have a login button.

Comment: No, if you scroll down the page you'll see other examples that do not require login.